# Job told me I had to make up the hours I was sick

Tags: salary, sickness, payroll, ireland

I called in sick to work on the Friday of last week so I missed 8 hours of work! My employer then informed me on the Monday when I had returned that he had already submitted payroll for the month on the 9th of December(even though we don’t get paid until new year) so I have to make up those extra hours. Is this normal protocol? I am only a Christmas temp so I finish up on the 3rd of January and he is asking me to complete the hours before December is over which seems impossible as I only have 3 days off over Christmas to be with family

Comment: This question really needs to day what country you are in, since laws on these things vary from place to place

Comment: I am from Ireland and I can’t find anything online which states what I should do! I have offered to work on the 4th of January (the day after I am due to finish work) but he says the hours have to be done before December finishes

Comment: I am working in Ireland.

Comment: @gnasher729 it wasn't obvious to you that he was saying where he worked? No need to be an ass

Comment: I think your boss is just trying to manipulate/bully you because he doesn't have enough people working over Christmas. Whatever happens, don't accept that nonsense. It's his mistake. His problem. Punishing you because you took a sick day is most likely very illegal where you are located.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they submitted their payroll even before you actually did the work, that is *their* problem and depending on jurisdiction even borderline illegal and/or tax fraud.

However, it's not your place to complain or rub it in if you want to stay on friendly terms with them. You can offer to pay them back if they accidentally overpay you. You can offer to work additional hours if you feel fit for it, even if it's not the full 8 in the end. But they cannot force you to do anything else.

Depending on your location, especially in many US states, they may however fire you for "no reason" or any other reason ("didn't meet our spontaneous scheduling demands" is as good as any other reason if you are in a country with non-existant worker protection laws). That sucks. But assuming you live in a democracy, it's up to you to change that at a voting booth.

Comment: This is actually a common thing but generally the company should be able to submit an amendment to the payroll.  I submit my hours for two weeks in advance.

Comment: Even if overpaid by accident or mistake, it's not really optional to pay the money back if they ask for it.

Comment: This question is tagged Ireland. It's possible that there are employee protection laws that might apply here.

Comment: In addition to this advice, I would suggest that she tries to have that conversation over email or over SMS if that's possible. A manager is much less likely to cross a line when they know their words are being memorialized. nvoigt, If you like this advice, please add it to your existing answer. This is not a new idea, I don't need the credit.